# Move a line before another in a multi-command sed file

Tags: sed

.

I have a text file similar to this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

and I need to:

1. move line `E` before line `C`;
2. replace line `C` with `X` (`X` could be multiline);
3. replace line `G` with `Y` (`Y` could be multiline);
4. remove lines `D` and `F`.

This is the `sed` file I have now:

```
/C/ c\
X
/G/ c\
Y
/D/ d
/F/ d
```

which does 2, 3, 4 but not 1. How can I fix the script to move `E` before `C`?

Note: I cannot rely on line numbers or contiguity of lines, which may vary; I can only rely on pattern matching.

Answer (score 5):

For your particular case, this will do:

```
sed '
/C/,/E/ {
        s/[CD]/&/
        t s
        s/E.*/&\
X1\
X2/
        t e
        H
        :s
        d
        :e
        p
        x
        D
}
/F/d
/G/c\
Y1\
Y2
' file
```

Someone smarter than me may be able to do it in a simpler way -- notice that this should handle the case where there are other lines than `D` between `C` and `E`. This assumes however that the `A`, `B`, ... lines are sorted, ie no `G` between `C` and `D`.

Generally, cases like this are done much more obviously with `ed` or `ex`:

```
$ ed <<'EOT' -s file
/E/m/C/-1
g/D/d
g/F/d
/C/c
X1
X2
.
/G/c
Y1
Y2
.
w
EOT

$ cat file
A
B
E
X1
X2
Y1
Y2
```

The `/PAT1/m/PAT2/-1` command will move the line matching `PAT1` before the line matching `PAT2`.

The `/PAT/c` command will change the line matching `PAT` to the following lines terminated by `.`.

The `g/PAT/d` command will go to all lines matching `PAT` and delete them.

I've changed the order of the operations based on @don_crissti's suggestions, in order to make the example a bit more general (handle the case where the `X1`, `Y1` inserted lines may match the `/D/` or `/F/` patterns).